# Regex find second / and count 5 characters onwards

Tags: regex

Is there a way to find and replace using regex here? I want to find the second `/`, then count 5 characters father and remove these 5 characters.

This:

```
fhp/wa_od/11111_picx
a_wpu/hxpokpa/HW18H_wdij
awo/p8i_dxawp/KW920poij_m
```

Should become this:

```
fhp/wa_od/_picx
a_wpu/hxpokpa/_wdij
awo/p8i_dxawp/poij_m
```

Comment: Which language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex which captures some optional text followed by `/`, whole of this pattern two times and groups them in group1, then captures 5 characters next to it and then groups remaining characters after those five characters in group2 and finally replaces by whatever matched by group1 and group2.

```
((?:.*?\/){2}).{5}(.*)
```

Replace it with \1\2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHeZzN/1)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folowing regex:

```
/(\w+?\/\w+?\/).{5}(.*)/g
```

It creates a capturing `Group` that matches one or more `Word` characters, followed by a `slash`, then again one or more `Word` character, followed by a `slash`. Then it matches 5 of any character, followed by a `Group` that matches the rest.

You then replace with:

```
$1$2 (or in some regex flavors: \1\2)
```